# linux can't delete users profile

Tags: linux, user-management

I have tried to delete none active users from the server, when I ran:

```
/usr/sbin/userdel -r
```

delete the user but not a home directory, and got this error:

> cannot remove ‘olduser/.bash_history’: Operation not permitted

I have tried to remove manually as root:

```
rm -fR olduser
```

I got the same not permitted. What else I can try to remove this user home directories?

Comment: Is the home directory an NFS-mounted file system?  What does `lsattr ~olduser/.bash_history` say?

Comment: are you running commands as `root`?

Comment: not nfs mounted. lsattr output = -------------e-- .bash_history. yes I am running as root.

Comment: what are the normal permissions with ls -la

Comment: also could you give the output from mount | grep "^/dev"

Comment: -rw-r--r-- for .bash_profile. there is no mount for user

Comment: Could you give the output of `lsof +D /path/to/olduser/home/ | grep bash_history`?

Comment: @Jose- return nothing

Comment: mmm... Where is mounted your /path/to/olduser/hom‌​e/ ?

Comment: there is no mount.

Comment: How could be that?

Answer (score 2):

after few search. I did

> ```
>   lsattr .bash_history
> ```
>
> and return

----a-------e-- .bash_history

so, I have run

> ```
> chattr -a
> ```

after that I am able to delete .bash_history